# Android app force closes when the button is clicked to go on another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, forceclose

I am making an android app using android 2.2 and eclipse.
Its a simple app which should change activities from "CoverPageApp.java" to "LoginActivity.java" 
and then to another activity.
But as I click the "Start Button" in CoverPageApp.java,  the app force closes.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnLinkToRegistrScrn;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.login);
     addListenerOnButton();
     btnLinkToRegistrScrn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LinkToRegisterScreen); 

   }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context2 = this;

        Button loginbtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

            loginbtn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context2, DashboardActivity.class);
                         context2.startActivity(intent);   
            }

        });
    }


    { 
        // Link to Register Screen 
        btnLinkToRegistrScrn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
           @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { 
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CAActivity.class); 
                startActivity(i); 
                } 
       }); 

    }   

   }
```

**LogCat**

```
05-31 12:37:08.620: D/AndroidRuntime(629): Shutting down VM
05-31 12:37:08.620: W/dalvikvm(629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 05-31 12:37:08.630: E/AndroidRuntime(629): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.trekeyes.android/com.trekeyes.android.LoginActivity}; **have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Comment: +1 on the comment for the nice copy/paste from LOGCAT

Comment: @Skies Sorry for not adding the manifest file. Since I have declared it in the manifest file but still that same error occurs "force close". And when I click on the errors in LogCat it points at the line **startActivity(intent1);** in **CoverPageApp.java**. Help plz.

Comment: <activity android:name=".loginActivity"></activity> try with a capital **L**

Comment: @Skies Sorry it didnot help. Now this error is occuring:  **          05-31 17:36:09.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):  at com.trekeyes.android.LoginActivity.<init>(LoginActivity.java:51)** ----------------------------------------------------------- `Logcat directs it in this line in LoginActivity:`        ** btnLinkToRegistrScrn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not added the activity

```
LoginActivity.java
```

in Android manifest file
Just add followin code to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already declared this in my manifest file. I have added the manifest you can take a look at it. Plz I would appreciate your help.  When I click on the errors in LogCat it points at the line **startActivity(intent1);** in **CoverPageApp.java**. Help plz.

Answer (score 2):

please check below :

open your manifest file :

[image]

now add activity :

[image]

[image]

[image]

save your manifest file and run your project again.

and now your manifest.xml look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test_new"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Test_newActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: ThankYou very much for your help I have added the manifest file you can take a look at it. Plz I would appreciate your help.  When I click on the errors in LogCat it points at the line **startActivity(intent1);** in **CoverPageApp.java**. Help plz.